# Replacing one line of a file with contents of two files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently writing an script which is replacing the line of a file with the content of two other files and right after writes the new line to a new file. But when running my script only the content of the first file was replaced with the content of the line.

My code:

```
with open('file1.txt','r') as file1, open('file2.txt','r') as file2, \
     open('original.txt','r') as original:
    for lines in original:
        with open('sample.txt','w') as sample:
            for line in file1:
                sample.write(lines.replace(line,''))
        sample.close()
        with open('sample.txt','w') as sample:
            for line in file2:
                sample.write(lines.replace(line,''))
        sample.close()
```

Content of my file1:

```
Python
```

Content of my file2:

```
Pascal
```

Content of my original file:

```
I Python like Pascal cookies
```

Content of the new file after running my script:

```
I like Pascal cookies
```

What the content of the new file should actually look like after running my script:

```
I like cookies
```

Am I doing something wrong? Could someone tell me what's wrong and help solve this problem?

Comment: what is the criterium to replace a line of the original? how do you know which line should be replaced?

Comment: @cards in the original will always be only one line.

Comment: @cards in the main file the original will be just a temporary file

Comment: I don't really undestand what you're doing or trying to do. However, code-wise I noticed two things. 1.) You don't need to explicitly close file you have opened with a `with` statement (although doing so is harmless). 2.) The second time you `open('sample.txt','w')` overwrites the contents of the file that was written the first time.

Comment: Try to think carefully about your logic. Work through it step by step. Try physically writing down example files on pieces of paper and executing the code step by step, physically flipping over the pages to represent opening and closing the files, using pencils to point at the current line in the file, etc. You should clearly  see that it doesn't work.

Comment: Also, while I'm here: the **entire point** of using `with open('sample.txt','w') as sample:` is that `sample.close()` becomes unnecessary. Don't add that in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that your `replace`s are targeting always to the original value, `lines` so your multiple changes do not accumulate.
So for example

```
a = 'ciao'
a.replace('i', 'I')
print(a)
```

will print `ciao` since replace return a new string (strings are immutable) object which you need to store in some variable otherwise... just useless

Here a solution

```
with open('./file1','r') as file1, open('./file2','r') as file2, open('original','r') as original:

    with open('sample.txt','w') as sample:
        a = original.read()
        b = a.replace(file1.read(), '')
        c = b.replace(file2.read(), '')
        
        sample.write(c)
    
with open('sample.txt', 'r') as fd: print(fd.read())
```

Output

```
I  like  cookies
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another example using list

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.7
with(open('file1','r') as f1,
     open('file2', 'r') as f2,
     open('original', 'r') as orig,
     open('new.txt', 'w') as newfile):

    origtxt = orig.read()
    tmplist = [f1.read(),f2.read()]
    
    for i in range(len(tmplist)):
        origtxt = origtxt.replace(f'{tmplist[i]} ','')
    newfile.write(origtxt)
```

I didn't account for new lines in the above.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.7
with open('file1','r') as f1,       \
     open('file2', 'r') as f2,      \
     open('original', 'r') as orig, \
     open('new.txt', 'w') as newfile:
     
    origtxt = orig.read()
    tmplist = f'{f1.read()}'.split('\n') + f'{f2.read()}'.split('\n')
              
    print(tmplist)
    for i in range(len(tmplist)):
        origtxt = origtxt.replace(f'{tmplist[i]}', '')
        origtxt = origtxt.replace('  ',' ')
    #newfile.write(origtxt)
    print(origtxt)
```